# What's wrong?undefined reference?

Tags: c++

```
ERROR CODE:

    CList<CString,const char*> test;

ERROR INFO:
    ECLIPSE / UBUNTU 10

/home/latyas/workspace/CList/Debug/../test.cpp:7: undefined reference
            to `CList<CString, char const*>::CList()'
```

I have already defined this constructor:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> CList<T1, T2>::CList() :
        m_nHead(0), m_nTail(0),m_nCount(0) {
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

updated:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CString.h"
#include "CList.h"

int main()
{
    CList<CString,const char*> test;
    test.AddHead("test");
    return 0;
}


/*
 * CList.h
 *
 *  Created on: 2012-3-31
 *      Author: latyas
 */

#ifndef CLIST_H_
#define CLIST_H_


template<typename T1,typename T2> class CList {
public:
    struct CNode {
        CNode* pNext;
        CNode* pPrev;
        T1 data;
    };
    CList();
    ~CList();
    long GetHead();
    long GetTail();
    long GetNext(long, T1&); 
    long GetCount();
    long AddHead(T2);
    long AddTail(T2);
    long RemoveAt(long);

private:
    CNode* m_nHead;
    CNode* m_nTail;
    long m_nCount;

};

#endif /* CLIST_H_ */

/*
 * CList.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 2012-3-31
 *      Author: latyas
 */

#include "CList.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

/
template<typename T1, typename T2> CList<T1, T2>::CList() :
        m_nHead(0), m_nTail(0),m_nCount(0) {
}
template<class T1, class T2> CList<T1, T2>::~CList() {
    std::cout << "~CList()";
```

Comment: Going to need to see more code.

Comment: and where your header? please, write it and your class definition

Comment: All template definitions have to go in the *header*, and *not* into a .cpp file.

Comment: `CString` ? Are you trying to use MFC under Linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no .cpp file for templated classes, so all your implementation must be done in the .h file only..

```
/*
 * CList.h
 */

#ifndef CLIST_H_
#define CLIST_H_


template<typename T1,typename T2> class CList {
public:
    struct CNode {
        CNode* pNext;
        CNode* pPrev;
        T1 data;
    };
    CList();
    ~CList();
    long GetHead();
    long GetTail();
    long GetNext(long, T1&); 
    long GetCount();
    long AddHead(T2);
    long AddTail(T2);
    long RemoveAt(long);

private:
    CNode* m_nHead;
    CNode* m_nTail;
    long m_nCount;

};

#endif /* CLIST_H_ */

/* ========== Implementation of Clist class ============ */

template<typename T1, typename T2> CList<T1, T2>::CList() :
        m_nHead(0), m_nTail(0),m_nCount(0) {
}
template<class T1, class T2> CList<T1, T2>::~CList() {
    std::cout << "~CList()";
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say *where* you defined it. I guess you did so in some implementation file. However for templates the implementation has to go into the header file (unless you explicitly instantiate them for every type they might be used for).

For this, it's helpful to think of templates as a sort of type-safe macro (however note that templates are far more complex than macros, so please don't overstretch that analogy). Just like macros, templates contain instructions on how to create code; it's at a different level (macros at the textual level, templates on the syntax level), but the basic principle is the same: The template *is not* the code, it *generates* the code. A template which you never instantiate will not show up in your compiled code *at all*.

At the place where you define your variable `test` you *instantiate* the template `CTest` for the types `CString` and `const char*`. That is, you instruct the compiler to generate a concrete class `CList<CString, const char*>` from your `CList` template. However since at that place, the compiler cannot see the definition of the destructor, it cannot generate it. However it doesn't complain because it doesn't know that you didn't instantiate it elsewhere for those types. However it generates a reference to it, so that it gets called on execution.

In the implementation file, the compiler *does* see your constructor template, however you don't instantiate it there, therefore the compiler doesn't generate any code from it (it couldn't do so anyways because it cannot know with which types you might instantiate the class elsewhere).

Now on linking, the linker sees the reference to the constructor `CList<CString, const char*>::CList()` (from your file which defined `test`), but no definition for it (because none was generated). And therefore it complains about the missing reference.

Comment: i defined the constructor and destrcutor in the head file,and error disapeared,but other functions occured the same errors.

Comment: Then those other functions are probably also templated (other member functions of the same template?). What I wrote applies to *all* templates.

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined reference" is most likely a linker error, i.e. the linker cannot find a library referenced by Your source code.

You are using `CString`. Which library is it from? Is this library known to the linker?

Comment: I have already added this " #include "CList.h" " in pre-treatment. CList.h >> template<typename T1,typename T2> class CList {
public:
 CList(){}